# Empty href tag returns current url on remote server

Tags: url

I left a few href tags without values. However after deploying the application to a remote server, those tags get filled with the url corresponding to the app location on that server.

So, if my application lived at http://www.foo.org/, `href = ""` gets replaced with `href = "http://www.foo.org/"`.

Why?

Comment: What web server are you using? What web browser are you using?

Comment: @austinian AWS Bucket (Linux I guess). Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design.

According to [RFC 2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt):

> A URI reference that does not contain a URI is a reference to the
>      current document.  In other words, an empty URI reference within a
>      document is interpreted as a reference to the start of that document,
>      and a reference containing only a fragment identifier is a reference
>      to the identified fragment of that document.  Traversal of such a
>      reference should not result in an additional retrieval action.
>      However, if the URI reference occurs in a context that is always
>      intended to result in a new request, as in the case of HTML's FORM
>      element, then an empty URI reference represents the base URI of the
>      current document and should be replaced by that URI when transformed
>      into a request.